# How to select a specific person in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created the following tables:

```
create table people
(
        ID               varchar(10),
        name             varchar(35),

CONSTRAINT pk_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)

);

create table numbers
(
        code             varchar(10),
        ID               varchar(10),
        number           numeric,

CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)

);
```

I inserted the following datas:

```
insert into people(ID, name) 
values('fdx1','Peter');
insert into people(ID, name) 
values('fdx2','Alice');
insert into people(ID, name) 
values('fdx3','Louis');

insert into numbers(code, ID, number) 
values('001','fdx1',1);
insert into numbers(code, ID, number) 
values('002','fdx1',1);
insert into numbers(code, ID, number) 
values('003','fdx2',2);
insert into numbers(code, ID, number) 
values('004','fdx2',3);
insert into numbers(code, ID, number) 
values('005','fdx3',4);
insert into numbers(code, ID, number) 
values('006','fdx3',4);
```

My problem is: how to select people that has the same number. For example "Peter" and "Louis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "same number" you mean that there is only one number in `numbers` for the person.  You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select n.id
from numbers n
group by n.id
having min(number) = max(number);
```

Note:  this doesn't take `NULL` into account.  Your question doesn't specify what to do if one of the values is `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff for the answer. But how to do that if it was not a number but a string.

Comment: @Python241820 . . . I don't understand your question.  This will work on almost any data type including strings.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to see out of the 2 rows for each user in numbers who has the same number twice? If so you could do.

```
SELECT p.ID, p.name, p.number, COUNT(DISTINCT n.id) as num
FROM people as p
INNER JOIN numbers as n on n.ID = p.ID
GROUP BY p.ID, n.number
HAVING num > 1
```

The would return a list of people how have the same number in numbers more than once

In case this was not what you were looking for some other things you could do are:

To return a list of people for a specific number you could do the following

```
SELECT p.ID, p.name
FROM people as p
INNER JOIN numbers as n on n.ID = p.ID
WHERE n.number = [[X]]
```

You would replace [[X]] with the number e.g. 1 this would then return a list of people who are linked to number 1 in this case Peter

If you wanted a list of all people and their associated number you could do:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.name, n.number
FROM people as p
INNER JOIN numbers as n on n.ID = p.ID
ORDER BY n.number
```

This would return the users ID, Name and their associated number.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query:

```
select     p.name, n.number, count(*) repeats
from       people p
inner join numbers n on n.ID = p.ID
group by   p.id, n.number
having     count(*) > 1
```

This lists the names of the people who have a duplicate number. That number is included in the output, and the number of times it occurs.

Output:

```
|  name | number | repeats |
|-------|--------|---------|
| Peter |      1 |       2 |
| Louis |      4 |       2 |
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3eedf2/3)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But if i add other number different for "Louis" or "Peter" MySQL continues showing "Louis" and "Peter".

Comment: Yes, that is intended. Was you question different? Can you clarify? I just reread your question, and it does say *"how to select people that has the same number"*. Even if you add another number to Luis, if he has the same number at least once, then that is a positive... I think your question was not clear. :-(